# Audit changes to stored procedures in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to log changes to stored procedures and tables in SQL Server 2000?

I need to track if users use create, drop, or alter commands

Comment: Probably you can use a SQL trace on 'Object:Created', 'Object:Deleted', 'Object:Altered' events, similar to the default trace that comes out the box on 2005

Comment: Yikes, Sql Server 2000 has been end of life for some time now... open security issues do not have patches. It's irresponsible and dangerous to still be using this old version, especially when supported versions are freely available.

Comment: Solve the actual problem - users that cannot be trusted. Either put your schema into source control or do not give them the permissions to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

[DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) have only been introduced in SQL Server 2005.

Generally, it's easier not to grant common users the permission to `CREATE TABLE` etc.

See [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) for information on `GRANT`, `REVOKE` etc